# react router v6：how to set a route with absolute path？

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

if click the NavLink, go to /search, and Search will be displayed

how to solve this in router v6? help please!!!

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter basename={'/index'}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path={'/A/*'} element={<Home/>} />
          <Route path={'/search/*'} element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>

    </div>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Home</div>
      <NavLink to={'/search'}>Search</NavLink>
      <Routes>
        <Route path={'/search'} element={<Search/>}/>
        <Route path={'/B/B1/show'} element={<Show/>}/>
      </Routes>
      <div>Footer</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While React Router claims that absolute file paths still work in V6 on [their website](https://remix.run/blog/react-router-v6):

> Note: Absolute paths still work in v6 to help make upgrading easier. You can even ignore relative paths altogether and keep using absolute paths forever if you'd like. We won't mind.

I'm not convinced it actually does for a subset of users who want this.

You can see the merge request for this functionality [here](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/pull/7992) but it explicitely calls out that this will only work if the child routes have the same path as the parent routes.

> Child routes with absolute paths that do not match their parent routes are an error.

Unfortunately for many of us, our child routes in websites using React Router pre-v6 don't have the same paths as their parent routes.

One possible solution is listed in [this thread](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8035#issuecomment-997737565) by user **@jampy** where they propose replacing the `Routes` component with a custom component that ignores the parent's path, thus allowing its `Route` components to use absolute paths.